# Remove default product gallery in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, zooming, gallery, product, magento2

As you know there is fotorama JavaScript gallery and magnifier in the product page of Magento 2. I need to know how I should remove it from my product page. I just need the product image only.

In my `app\design\frontend\Mypackage\mytheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml` file I removed:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
            "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
            "options": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",
                "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/loop"); ?>,
                "keyboard": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"); ?>,
                "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,
                "allowfullscreen": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"); ?>,
                "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                "thumbwidth": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",
                "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
                "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/navdir"); ?>"
            },
            "fullscreen": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav"); ?>",
                "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
            },
            "breakpoints": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getBreakpoints(); ?>
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `app\design\frontend\Mypackage\mytheme\etc\view.xml` file I removed:

```
  <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>

    <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    </var>

    <var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="navigation">dots</var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
    <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->
```

but no luck. Removing above code resulted in removing the product image and swatch functionalities. Can anyone help me with this? Is there any method that will allow me to remove the product gallery and zoom while keep the swatch function? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to display the main image of products, it is not necessary to remove the gallery.

You can disable magnifier and fullscreen features in your view.xml file.

```
...
<var name="gallery">
    ...
    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
    ...
</var>
...
<var name="magnifier">
    ...
    <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    ...
</var>
...
```

And use this simple module that allows you to display in the gallery only the main image.

Base folder: app\code

File: Example/OneImage/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "example/oneimage",
    "description": "OneImage module for Magento 2",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-catalog": "~100.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Example\\OneImage\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

File: Example/OneImage/registration.php

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Example_OneImage', __DIR__);
```

File: Example/OneImage/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_OneImage" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

File: Example/OneImage/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="ExampleOneImagePlugin" type="Example\OneImage\Plugin\Model\Product" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

File: Example/OneImage/Plugin/Model/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Example\OneImage\Plugin\Model;

/**
 * Plugin for \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * Retrieve media gallery images
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    public function afterGetMediaGalleryImages(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $images)
    {
        $mainImage = null;
        foreach ($images  as $key => $image) {
            if ($product->getImage() == $image->getFile()) {
                $mainImage = $image;
                break;
            }
        }
        $images->clear();
        if ($mainImage) {
            $images->addItem($mainImage);
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! thanks, edit the view.xml is the magento way for change values inside gallery.phtml

Answer (score 3):

If you need the main product image only, replace content of the gallery.phtml template with this code:

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();
$imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

if (!$product->getImage() || $product->getImage() == 'no_selection') {
    $image = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
} else {
    $image = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
            ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
            ->setImageFile($product->getImage())
            ->getUrl();
}
?>
<div class="gallery-placeholder">
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" >
</div>
```

But keep in mind that you will lose some of Magento 2 functionality (like a switching between images of associated products when selecting options).

Comment: Thank you. But I want to keep the swatch functionalities. Removing the original structure of HTML classes and ids removes the swatch functionality as you said. I have edited my question regarding this.